# How to load fancybox only once in DotNetNuke (DNN) (JS is already included in theme and modules)

Tags: javascript, duplicates, dotnetnuke, scriptmanager

I have a DotNetNuke website and I get a 'fancybox already initialized' error.

I would like to know how I can check and only include the JavaScript file once when the page load? I know that the Script Manager will only add the JS file once, but what if the skin does not use the Script Manager?

The theme includes the JavaScript file in the .ascx file in the following way:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server"
FilePath="js/jquery.fancybox3.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

My custom DNN module includes the same JS file using the Script Manager in the codebehind:

```
scriptInclude = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("script");
                scriptInclude.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
                scriptInclude.Attributes["src"] = this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.min.js";
                scriptInclude.ID = ID + "_6";

                Page.Header.Controls.Add(scriptInclude);
```

I need to add the Fancybox JS to all my modules because they can be installed on themes with Fancybox already included or not.

I need the Fancybox code included in the theme if the module is not placed on a particular page.

I have been thinking of creating a portal setting on all of my modules which will allows you to turn off the inclusion of the Fancybox JS file when it is already included in the theme.

I have looked at other posts, but my question involves DNN Modules and the Theme itself.

I did try to use this code in the theme from this post, but it seems not to work: [how to check if fancybox exists on page already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706145/how-to-check-if-fancybox-exists-on-page-already)

```
if(typeof $.fancybox == 'function') {
     fancy box loaded;
} else {
     fancy box not loaded;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally in this situation, I would ensure my modules all include the script using the Client Resource Management API (or the dnnJsInclude).  This can keep from multiple script registrations from the module added to the page multiple times.  But because you could have the script registered from a theme or module, it may not prevent duplicates because the path to the script will be different.

A better practice is to include Fancybox js library in your module and theme installation packages as a [Javascript Library extension](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/javascript-libraries) for DNN.  That will allow you to manage the javascript centrally in the CMS (under Settings > Extensions > Javascript Libraries) and include it in either your theme or module by *name* reference - which would eliminate duplicate includes on a page.

To do that, include the minified .js file in the root package zip and a new section in both theme and module .dnn manifest files:

```
<package name="Fancybox" type="JavaScript_Library" version="3.1.20">
  <friendlyName>jQuery Fancybox</friendlyName>
  <description>jQuery lightbox script for displaying images, videos and more.</description>
  <iconFile></iconFile>
  <owner>
    <name>fancyApps</name>
    <organization>fancyApps</organization>
    <url>http://www.fancyapps.com</url>
    <email>support@fancyapps.com</email>
  </owner>
  <license />
  <releaseNotes />
  <azureCompatible>true</azureCompatible>
  <dependencies />
  <components>
    <component type="JavaScript_Library">
      <javaScriptLibrary>
        <libraryName>Fancybox</libraryName>
        <fileName>jquery.fancybox.min.js</fileName>
        <objectName>fancybox</objectName>
        <cdnUrl>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.js"</cdnUrl>
        <preferredScriptLocation>PageHead</preferredScriptLocation>
      </javaScriptLibrary>
    </component>
    <component type="JavaScriptFile">
      <jsfiles>
        <libraryFolderName>Fancybox</libraryFolderName>
        <jsfile>
          <name>jquery.fancybox.min.js</name>
        </jsfile>
      </jsfiles>
    </component>
  </components>
</package>
```

This will attempt to install the Javascript Library with name "Fancybox" into your DNN environment from either the module or theme.

Change your script include in both your module and theme to the following:

C# code behind:

```
using DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries;
...
JavaScript.RequestRegistration("Fancybox");
JavaScript.Register(this.Page);
```

or .ASCX include:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="JavaScriptLibraryInclude" Src="~/admin/Skins/JavaScriptLibraryInclude.ascx" %>

<dnn:JavaScriptLibraryInclude runat="server" Name="Fancybox" />
```

Comment: The manifest file failed because there is a file name with extension.png. I did try to change this to the JS filename, but no luck. I removed the <component type="file"> section and it worked and installed. I only now have to get it to work in my module. When I add this code beneath the module package and when you select the install .zip file in DNN it shows: "Info Reading Component Manifest - JavaScriptFile Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file:" I am using a Christoc module template and the JS file is placed in a folder named Scripts in the module folder. Thx

Comment: I think you just need to change the line <jsfile<name>scripts/jquery.fancybox.min.js</name></jsfile> so that it looks for the js file in the proper place within the zip.

Comment: Also, I will remove the <component type="file"> section from my answer.  That was just for the extension icon which is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to change it, but I get this error in DNN. "Info Reading Component Manifest - JavaScriptFile
Failure File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DNNHosted\Install\Temp\svcom2pk\Scripts\jquery.fancybox.min-3.1.20.js"

Comment: Is there perhaps like a folder or basepath section DNN uses?

Comment: It still seems to not find the file in the zip package.  Did you confirm the zip package has the javascript file a "scripts" folder?  I'm not sure if Christoc template only includes .sql scripts in that folder when doing the release build packaging.  Maybe try putting into a different folder?

Comment: I did try to use a different folder as well, but it does not pick it up. When it builds it does include the file in the resources.zip file. Here is a link of the error: https://ibb.co/bQQZZ5. I have posted this question on DNN as well: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/combining-a-javascript-library-package-with-a-module-package-in-the-manifest-file, I even changed the path to ~/DesktopModules/ModuleName/Scripts but then it goes to install\Temp\jqeweq\~DesktopModules.. I have included a link to the Manifest: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/84a265af536a69ff5f4b0425e3b41010